Is this extra cycle before the MSB a common thing with serial bit timing?
The products that this is specifically around are the Pmod I2S2 which uses the Cirrus CS5343 ADC and CS4344 DAC.  It is plugged into a STM32F407G-DISC1.
Now I am having some trouble figuring out exactly how the STM32F407 does its SPI and DMA and whether this extra cycle can be understood by the serial port (and skipped over) or if we are actually reading in a spurious bit that we don't want in the word from the ADC and if we're sending out a bit to the DAC that is never read by it.

Here is the problem.  Normally with the word clock or the LR clock in the I2S 3-wire interface, a bit is latched at the very first active edge of the bit clock that occur immediately after the active edge of the word or LR clock.  Like this figure from the AK4954A:

But this is clearly not the case for the Cirrus chips:

The bits are read on the rising edge of the bit clock.  There is clearly intended that there is one rising edge that occurs after the LR clock edge that also occurs before the MSB of the data.  And, I don't believe this is normal.  I haven't seen this in other I2S implementations.
Now how is the STM32F407 supposed know about that extra bit after the word clock but before the MSB?  As best as I can tell, it's just going to read in whatever the serial data line is at that clock edge.
I am a DSP guy and not a hardware engineer.  But this affects the data in a very real way and I want to understand both what is meant to happen and what is actually happening, because I have to do the bit manipulation in my DSP processing code.  And I cannot tell if I will be lobbing off an extraneous bit or if I will be lobbing off the real MSB (which I don't want to do, of course).
Has anyone else dealt with this problem?  Are SPI ports programmable to either ignore or insert extra bits before the very first bit of data?  Has anyone has done this with an STM Arm chip?

The I²S specification says about the Word Select signal:


The WS line
changes one clock period before the MSB is transmitted. This allows
the slave transmitter to derive synchronous timing of the serial data
that will be set up for transmission. Furthermore, it enables the
receiver to store the previous word and clear the input for the next
word.

The AK4954A supports several sample formats, only some of which are I²S compatible; see figures 18…23:



All I²S devices support this one-bit delay. Like the AK4954A, most also support formats without this delay, usually called "left-justified" or "right-justified".

Thank you.  So I don't have access to the function definitions, but if I see code like this:
hi2s2.Instance = SPI2;
hi2s2.Init.Mode = I2S_MODE_MASTER_TX;
hi2s2.Init.Standard = I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS;
hi2s2.Init.DataFormat = I2S_DATAFORMAT_24B;
that looks like I2S is intended and that extra cycle will not be included in the bit transfers, right?

Yes. (There are other I2S_Standard_xxx values.)

So, last question: I2S_STANDARD_PHILIPS means that this extra cycle is completely accounted for and I need not worry about a spurious bit squatting in the location where my MSB is supposed to be?

Yes, the MSB on the wire is mapped to the MSB in memory.

Thank you.  I presumed as much.
